# Is work only a change of kinetic or potential energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

I find out on the internet that work is a transfer of energy essentially kinetic. What is the use of work if it does not consider all the types of energy applied , i mean sometimes an objects internal heat may be used to do work , but the equation of work will only consider its kinetic energy !

Comment: @JohnForkosh
 i am sorry but you took my words wrong . i meant that when for example we push an object some of the energy we applied converts into heat of the object and some of it gets stored as mechanical energy. But why do we consider this mechanical energy only as work and leave this heat energy aside.

Comment: Faiz Iqbal: In that case, I think they are referring to useful work done, which is defined as Force * Distance. Heat generated in that case is considered dissipated energy. For example moving a car to one mile is only useful work, the increased temprature of its engine, and tires, is of no use to us. The context seems to be efficiency.

Comment: @JohnForkosh and kvp
thanks for the comment , i have understood it now , thanks to your responses , it was just a misunderstanding of relating mechanical work to thermodynamic work

Comment: Now that you've understood, even in thermodynamics if you try to find the roots of __temperature__, you will trace it to the __kinetic energy__ of constituents, which is again a mechanical force.